# How to Configure BIND as referral

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, authoritative

I created a zone in a local BIND:

```
zone "labs" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.labs";
};

zone "foo.labs" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.foo.labs";
};
```

/etc/bind/db.labs:

```
@  3600  IN  SOA  labs.  root.labs.  (
   2019041900
   3600
   600
   604800
   600 )
   3600  IN  NS  ns1.labs.
   3600  IN  NS  ns2.labs.
   3600  IN  NS  ns3.labs.

ns1      IN  A  172.16.238.100
ns2      IN  A  172.16.238.110
ns3      IN  A  172.16.238.120
```

/etc/bind/db.foo.labs:

```
@  3600  IN  SOA  labs.  root.labs.  (
   2019041900
   3600
   600
   604800
   600 )
   3600  IN  NS  ns.foo.labs.

ns      IN  A  172.16.238.200
```

This BIND instance listens on `172.16.238.100` and I got another server listening on `172.16.238.200` that will serve the A record for `foo.labs`.

I would like my BIND instance to act as referral, meaning that if I query `dig @172.16.238.100 foo.labs` I should get the NS record (same behavior than the root servers, for example. `dig @a.gtld-servers.net. google.com A` gives me the NS record since it acts as referral)

But as of now:

```
dig @labs_bind9 foo.labs A

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foo.labs.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
foo.labs.       600 IN  SOA labs. root.labs. 2019041900 3600 600 604800 600
```

```
dig @labs_bind9 foo.labs NS

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foo.labs.          IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.labs.       3600    IN  NS  ns.foo.labs.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.foo.labs.        3600    IN  A   172.16.238.200
```

What is missing to force BIND to serve NS record in that case? how to make BIND as referral, I do not see anything in the documentation or example in the wild.

Comment: >I would like my BIND instance to act as referral, meaning if I query dig @172.16.238.100 foo.labs I got the NS record, like a root/TLD server.   What exactly you mean here? what is "tld server" in your case? What exact record you want to get? And add zone file names to content of zone files so i can figure out what config from what file and what $ORIGIN is

Comment: @gapsf I added zone file name to contents and change the wording for the root server example. The example is `dig @a.gtld-servers.net. google.com A` gives me NS records, I would like `dig @172.16.238.100 foo.labs. A` gives me the NS records

Comment: You don't have any delegation of `foo` in `labs` zone, aka  `NS` records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like my BIND instance to act as referral, meaning that if I query dig @172.16.238.100 foo.labs I should get the NS record (same behavior than the root servers, for example. dig @a.gtld-servers.net. google.com A gives me the NS record since it acts as referral)

Lets see what`s going on here

```
#dig @a.gtld-servers.net. google.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @a.gtld-servers.net. google.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56733
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.         172800  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns2.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.         172800  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns1.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.         172800  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns3.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         172800  IN      AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a
ns4.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 07 14:03:26 +06 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 287
```

Here you ask DNS server `a.gtld-servers.net.` to resolve IPv4 of `google.com` name for you recursively (`flags: qr`).

But `a.gtld-servers.net.` is not authoritative for `google.com` zone and is not allow recursive queries (see `;; WARNING: recursion requested but not availabl`) so it's answer is NOTHING for your's A query (`ANSWER: 0`).

But because `a.gtld-servers.net.` is  authoritative name server for `com.` zone is so kind to tell you which name servers are responsible for the `google.com.` zone meaning you should ask those servers for IPv4 address of `google.com` name (see `;; AUTHORITY SECTION:`).
These NS records are called **delegation records**.

Additionally, it reports the IP addresses of these name servers so you know them in advance to avoid delegation records resolving loop (see `;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:`).
These A records are called **glue record**.

So you may have it like this:

/etc/bind/db.labs:

```
@  3600  IN  SOA  labs.  root.labs.  (
   2019041900
   3600
   600
   604800
   600 )
   3600  IN  NS  ns1.labs.
   3600  IN  NS  ns2.labs.
   3600  IN  NS  ns3.labs.

foo          IN  NS ns.foo.labs. ; delegation for foo.labs.
ns.foo.labs. IN  A ip_of_ns.foo.labs. ; glue record

ns1      IN  A  172.16.238.100
ns2      IN  A  172.16.238.110
ns3      IN  A  172.16.238.120
```

Comment: Great! I definitely missed something in the format of the zone file. It works and makes my zone files simpler, thank you!